# Can I combine two Eclipse download packages?

Tags: eclipse, installation, package

I'm about to install Eclipse Kepler, from scratch. Now, the download page has, among others, both an 'Eclipse IDE for 'Eclipse for Parallel Application Developers' and a 'Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers. The former is larger in size than the standard package, so clearly they're not both subsets of the standard package.

Do I downloaded them both? If I should, how do I combine them after download? ; If I shouldn't, do I just download one any of them and then download packages for it? How can I download just the right packages, but all at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be to download one (like Parallel Application Developers) and then use `Help>Install New Software` to install CDT (C/C++).

There's no way to combine them if you download both, and no way to download everything at the same time (since you need at least 2 separate downloads).

There's a good information page on the different [package contents](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php?release=kepler).